# How to add empty alternative to drowpDownList

Tags: drop-down-menu, sharepoint-2007

I am populating dropdownlist like this:

```
SPList categories = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Categories"];
                dropdownlist.DataSource = categories.Items;
                dropdownlist.DataValueField = "ID";
                dropdownlist.DataTextField = "Title";
                dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Let say, if user do not want to select any value from dropdownlist, but want to select an empty option. how i add an empty alternative to dropdownlist ??

Comment: Did my solution work for you? Please follow up and mark an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line after you populate the ddl

```
dropdownlist.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select Value", "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Choice fields, the default value is configured in the column settings. If the "Default value" input box is populated, delete the value in order to use no default value.